# Change all image textures folder location together

Tags: path

I just downloaded a Kitbash mini-kit blender file and all the references to images are looking in the wrong folder.

Is there a way to change all of the images to look in a specific folder? At the moment I'm doing them one by one and it's pretty painful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to [Find Missing Files](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/topbar.html?highlight=find%20missing%20files):

[image]

select image folder and check **Find All**, to search not just missing files:

[image]